# Replace data attribute html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello guys how i can replace data attribute, for example i use with a script for video background but when i detect mobile i want to change video with one more light.So i did this in js file

```
/* Add your custom JavaScript code */
$(document).ready(function(){

  if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|OperaMini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
     $('.fullscreen').attr('data-vide-bg', 'homepages/portfolio/video/mobile');
  }
});
```

And in index.html for background video

```
<section class="fullscreen" data-video-bg="homepages/portfolio/video/merge-kqwil">
<section>
```

So what i want is when detect mobile replace this video background with `"homepages/portfolio/video/mobile"` instead of `homepages/portfolio/video/merge-kqwil`

I use as plugin for bg video [VideoBg](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide#readme) when is detect mobile he put a png or JPG but i want to change with this video for mobile.
Thank you!

Comment: You have sytax error there is that intentional? `data-vide-bg`, missing single quote

Comment: Only here i have that syntax error.My bad!

Comment: @VaRecomand  then correct it

Comment: I did and is not change the attr.

Comment: in your section tag use **data-vide-bg** attribute and check again

Comment: did you try to change it with next script `$('#myBlock').vide('path/to/video');` as in documentation?

Comment: I did and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing single quote at the end.

```
/* Add your custom JavaScript code */
$(document).ready(function(){

  if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $('.fullscreen').attr('data-vide-bg','homepages/portfolio/video/mobile');
   };
});
```

One more mistake in `HTML` data attribute `data-video-bg`, change to `.data-vide-bg`

Hope this will help.

Comment: Isn`t working is same thing,because he have fallback this plugin [https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide#readme ]
 so if he detect mobile he put a JPG or PNG but i don`t know how to change that.

Comment: `data attribute` in `HTML` should be `data-vide-bg`

Comment: @VaRecomand . Try `setTimeout` of **1sec** after being detected device as mobile. Hope this will solve you problem.

Answer (score 0):

Code seems working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera 
 Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
   $('.fullscreen').attr('data-vide-bg', 
  'homepages/portfolio/video/mobile');
};
});
```

Missing single quote in the end try and revert back

Comment: still not working , here is the plugin what i use for bg video https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide#readme

Comment: @VaRecomand  why not you corrected your syntax in your question.every-one pointing out to that.